# Unable to create Conditional Access policy in AzureAD with Conditional Access App Control

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

When we are trying to create Conditional Access policy in AzureAD with "Block Download"/"Use Custom Policy" in session under "Use Conditional Access App Control", we are getting the "Uncaught TypeError: f is not a function" error in browser console. Attached is the screenshot of the same.
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2VAH.png)

Comment: This seems weird, try to logout and login azure portal again and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the "Validating policy" error in my Azure Portal. I guess it is a problem of Azure itself, you could contact with MS supporter.

There is a workaround with Microsoft Graph API.

1.Sign in with your Global Administrator account on [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

2.[Create conditionalAccessPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/conditionalaccessroot-post-policies?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and there are the [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/conditionalaccesspolicy?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) of conditionalAccessPolicy.

**Note:** consent some permissions under Modify Permissions.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/identity/conditionalAccess/policies
Content-type: application/json

{
    "displayName": "Demo app for documentation",
    "state": "disabled",
    "conditions": {
        "signInRiskLevels": [
            "high",
            "medium"
        ],
        "clientAppTypes": [
            "mobileAppsAndDesktopClients",
            "exchangeActiveSync",
            "other"
        ],
        "applications": {
            "includeApplications": [
                "All"
            ],
            "excludeApplications": [
                "00000007-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
            ],
            "includeUserActions": []
        },
        "users": {
            "includeUsers": [
                "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
            ],
            "excludeUsers": [
                "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "GuestsOrExternalUsers"
            ],
            "includeGroups": [],
            "excludeGroups": [],
            "includeRoles": [
                "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
            ],
            "excludeRoles": [
                "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
            ]
        },
        "platforms": {
            "includePlatforms": [
                "all"
            ],
            "excludePlatforms": [
                "iOS",
                "windowsPhone"
            ]
        },
        "locations": {
            "includeLocations": [
                "AllTrusted"
            ],
            "excludeLocations": [
                "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
            ]
        }
    },
    "grantControls": null,
    "sessionControls": {
        "applicationEnforcedRestrictions": null,
        "persistentBrowser": null,
        "cloudAppSecurity": {
            "cloudAppSecurityType": "blockDownloads",
            "isEnabled": true
        },
        "signInFrequency": {
            "value": 4,
            "type": "hours",
            "isEnabled": true
        }
    }
}
```

There is a similar issue [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/conditional-access-policy-will-not-save-quot-validating-policy/m-p/2222549/highlight/true).